# PSQLException for relation OneToOne: relation "car_model" does not exist

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I made OneToOne (one directional) relation in my Spring Boot (with Postgresql DB) app between two models (`car_model` and `car_picture_model`). After launching and inserting data (from java code) I can get correct relation info:

```
id | make    | car_image_id
 1 | Ferrari |            2
```

And I can select all cars and all images. DBeaver shows both tables and relation arrow.

But in logs I can see Exception:

> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
>           at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>       ...
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
>       Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "car_model" does not exist
>           at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2182) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]

Full log: https://pastebin.com/ui1Cj99j 
Removing name ="cars" does not change anything. 
Same as adding @Table annotation with car_name

CarModel:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity(name = "cars")
public class CarModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String make;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_image_id", unique = true)
    private CarPictureModel carPictureModel;

// Getters and Setters

}
```

CarPictureModel:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class CarPictureModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String fileName;

    @Column
    private String fileType;

    @Lob
    @Column
    private byte[] data;

//    for (bidirectional mapping)
//    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "carPictureModel")
//    private CarModel carModel;

// Getters and Setters

}
```

In `application.properties` there are both:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Can you help me and tell what I'm missing here ?

Comment: Check if the DB your are checking in and DB of your application are the same. from the stack you pasted, it seems like the drop statements are failing. hibernate is trying to dorp table that is not there. Or as @Jawa said add the `@table` annotations.

Answer (score 0):

It Looks like you are missing the @Table annotation. If your table name is car_model, please use @Table(name = "car_model") just before your class definition.

Same with the CarPictureModel as well.

`@Entity(name = "cars")
  @Table(name = "car_model")
  public class CarModel {
    }`

`@Entity
  @Table(name = "car_picture_model")
  public class CarPictureModel {
    }`

Comment: I tried it before and unfortunately it does not change output of thrown exception.

Answer (score 0):

@Rohit gave me a good hint. 
I chaned `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`
 to `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` and the problem is gone.
Now i got in logs:

```
Hibernate: alter table car_model drop constraint FKjlrfjf7bhyha1pkb0004q6l6w
Hibernate: drop table if exists car_model cascade
Hibernate: drop table if exists car_picture_model cascade
Hibernate: drop sequence if exists hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence start 1 increment 1
Hibernate: create table car_model (id int4 not null, color varchar(255), make varchar(255), mfy int4, model varchar(255), car_image_id int4, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table car_picture_model (id int4 not null, data oid, file_name varchar(255), file_type varchar(255), primary key (id))
```

So it looks like both `create` and `create-drop` first drops all tables before creating new one. When the problem occurred there were no tables to drop because `create-drop` droped earlier all tables when stopping server with ctrl-c. As this logs shows:

```
SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed drop of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
Hibernate: alter table car_model drop constraint FKjlrfjf7bhyha1pkb0004q6l6w
Hibernate: drop table if exists car_model cascade
Hibernate: drop table if exists car_picture_model cascade
Hibernate: drop sequence if exists hibernate_sequence
```